# Downloading source from a remote git repository with Powershell

Tags: git, powershell, automation

Basically what I'm trying to do is **download all the source code from a git repository I have hosted in a Visual Studio TFS 2015. With a Powershell script.**

The end goal is to develop an automation which would then pick up that code, do some stuff to it and push it to another server.

The thing is, so far the only way I know of obtaining the code is to authenticate to the system and then `git clone` the repository. On the other hand, first I don't really want that dependency with git since I only want the files, and second, I don't want to clone the repository, concept-wise.

All in all, any insight as into how to achieve this is appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to clone a Git repository, but you want it not depending on Git? Is it the moral of the story?

Comment: @vahdet Well, as far as I thought about it, I want to get the files. but I don't need the .git directory nor anything regarding git. Does it make sense?

Comment: Try `git archive --remote=<repo> --format=zip -o foo.zip <commit>`. "repo" is the url of the remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a file stored within a Git repo in TFS you make use of the [items](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/items) API.

The format of this API looks like this:

```
https://{instance}/{project}defaultcollection/_apis/git/repositories/{repository}/items?api-version={version}&scopepath={filepath}[&includecontentmetadata={bool}&lastprocessedchange={bool}]
```

A real-world example of this API (with variable replacement) might look like this:

```
https:/mytfs:8080/defaultcollection/MyProject/_apis/git/repositories/MyRepo/items?api-version=1.0&scopepath=ReadMe.md
```

In the above example, I am attempting to download a file named ReadMe.md from a Git repo named MyRepo in the project named MyProject.

You can use the `Invoke-RestMethod` Powershell method to get the results.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like something I want to do! Thanks :)